# Biblatex Math using ieee-alphabetic style

Tags: math-mode, biblatex

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=ieee-alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
  @book{tst,
        author = {Smith, John},
        title = {\(\pm\) On the run},
        year = {2010}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\nocite{*}
\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I'm having trouble compiling the previous source.
The Error messages state something about `missing {`
while this is clearly not the case. 
However, if I remove the `bibstyle` setting I can compile
without any problems. Since I need to use this particular
style this is not an options.
Does someone know how to fix the math related issue?

Comment: Have you tried with "style=..." instead of "bibstyle=..."?

Comment: Don't use the `minimal` class. With `article` it compiles fine.

Comment: @karlkoeller Indeed this was an issue with the minimal class.

Comment: Cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114/15925

Comment: @karlkoeller May be you should make that answer, or we should register this as a "duplicate" of minimal class question in my previous comment.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Better the duplicate link, I think.